# Excel editing command button name not changing

Tags: excel, vba

When I am editing command button and I go to the top left corner to change the name of the command button it allows me to edit the text and change it but when I press enter or click somewhere the name of the button keeps reverting back to the original name.

I've tried also tried making sure design mode is selected as well, and the command button and the sheet do not have any protection on either

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Comment: have you checked that you don't already have a button with the name your are trying to change it to? Try a different name and see if that works.

Comment: What name are you trying to give exactly?

Comment: thanks vba4all it wasnt that I had another button with that name on my sheet it was that at some point I had had a button with that name and I needed to delete it from my module inorder to allow me to use it again, I wouldnt have thought of looking for that if you hadnt have mention about another button with the same name

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. Solved! My problem was that I would create an ACTIVEX button, and using the properties, give it a customized name (changing CommandButton1 to something much more descriptive)... then later, upon saving and re-opening the excel, some of these buttons (not all) would revert to CommandButtonX.

The whole problem was THE LENGTH OF THE NAME. My names that failed would be around 39 chars or more (somewhere around 39). Using the selection objects pane under the Excel "Find and Select" menu item, I observed the ones that would fail vs succeed.... comparing what I would change in that pane with control properties (Name) and the excel "sheet Name Box" in the upper left area of the sheet screen.

Answer (score 0):

When we have to rename the command button, you can use properties and namebox. But the purpose to change the appearance of button, you have to go to 
properties->caption. In caption, you can rename button's appearance.